# How to form Restsharp Get Request with Oauth2 and display it via console

Tags: c#, api, rest, oauth-2.0, restsharp

I am wondering if anyone knows how to do make a Get request with Oauth2 and display it on the console? Here is my code so far:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string url = "https://api.test";

        var client = new RestClient(url);

        var request = new RestRequest();

        request.AddHeader("Client-Id", "placeholder");
        request.AddHeader("Bearer", "placeholder");

        var response = client.GetAsync(request);

        Console.WriteLine(response);

        Console.Read();
    }
```

Comment: GetAsync returns a Task. You have to `await` it to get the response

Comment: Also, you don't add a Bearer header, you add an Authorization header with the value of Bearer and the token